# Solving the harmonic oscillator by using Hamilton-Jacobi formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism

In order to solve the harmonic oscillator,
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{q^2}{2},$$
by using Hamilton-Jacobi theory we have to find a complete solution for the H-J equation,
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial q}\right)^2+\frac{q^2}{2}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=0.$$
We seek for a solution
$$S=W(q)+T(t),$$
which leads to the following ODE,
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-\alpha t,$$
$$\frac{dW}{dq}=\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2}.\tag 1$$

It is easy to solve those equations and then write $S(q,\alpha,t)$, from which we can get
$$\beta=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \alpha}\Rightarrow q=\sqrt{2\alpha}\sin (t+\beta).$$

Now it comes my issue. When solving for momenta,
$$p=\frac{\partial S}{\partial q}=\frac{dW}{dq}=\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2},\tag 2$$
and using the solution found for $q$ we obtain
$$p=\sqrt{2\alpha}\sqrt{\cos^2(t+\beta)}=\sqrt{2\alpha}|\cos(t+\beta)|.$$

We know that the solution should be $p=\sqrt{2\alpha}\cos(t+\beta)$. I realize that even Eq. (2) is allowing only for positive momentum. So how to obtain the correct solution without forcing it by knowing the correct answer *a priori*?

Note that in obtaining (1) we actually should write 
$$\frac{dW}{dq}=\pm\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2},$$
but yet there is an ambiguity with the plus or minus sign.

Comment: You have two solutions $\pm\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2}$.

Comment: Exactly, but is there any way of eliminating the ambiguity of the plus or minus sign without knowing the solution a priori?

Answer (score 1):

By making use of Hamilton's equation to the Hamiltonian given, yeilds: $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = p$, which unambiguously implies $p = \sqrt{2 \alpha} \cos (t + \beta)$.

Comment: So I should use Eq. (1) as $\frac{dW}{dq}=\pm\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2}$ which gives $p=\pm\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2}=\pm\sqrt{2\alpha}|\cos (t+\beta)|$ and choose the correct sign by means of the Hamilton's equation? It works good enough for me, I just thought that once the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism is established, we did not need to trace things back to Hamiltonian formalism.

Comment: Well, the equation for q is completely determined by the Hamilton-Jacobi equations and the 2 constants of motion, as you correctly found. But i don't see how to relate this back to momentum p without making use of the Hamilton formalism. If this remains unclear I will edit my answer and elaborate further tomorrow.